# 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

i want to export from data in excel

and i try below code

```
def exel_all_attendance(request,course_id):
    all_submit_attendance = SubmitedAttendance.objects.filter(course_id=course_id)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=course.xlsx'
    attendance_workbook = Workbook()
    attendance_worksheet = attendance_workbook.active
    attendance_worksheet.title = 'list_hozor_qiab'
    columns = [att.submit_time for att in all_submit_attendance.all()]
    row_num = 1
    for col_num, column_title in enumerate(columns, 1):
        cell = attendance_worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell.value = column_title
    attendance_workbook.save(response)
    return response
```

but i get this error

```
AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

and I checked where the error is?

```
attendance_workbook.save(response)
```

any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok

i solve it

replace

```
attendance_workbook.save(response)
```

to

```
response.content = save_virtual_workbook(attendance_workbook)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-as-a-stream) and is the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

Given an OpenPyXL workbook `wb`:

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from django.http import HttpResponse

with NamedTemporaryFile() as temporary_file:
    wb.save(temporary_file.name)
    temporary_file.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(temporary_file.read(), content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="course.xlsx"'
    return response
```